# Проверка поля input на максимальную длину не больше десяти элементов

Tags: javascript

Создал 2 события `onekeyup` и `onchange` (для проверки как раз длины не больше десяти цифр). Функция работает неправильно. Как поставить условия, чтобы можно было вводить не больше десяти цифр? Спасибо.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);" onchange="checkLength();" placeholder="Enter data" >

function checkLength() 
{
  var element = document.getElementById('t');
  if(document.createEvent)
  {
      var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      e.initEvent('change', false, true);
      element.dispatchEvent(e);
      alert("ivalid length - 10 characters only!");
      return element;
  }   

}
```

---

ограничивать ввод елементов,грубо говоря что бы елементов было не больше 10-ти

maxlength для ввода клавиатурой,а не через  кнопки

Comment: вероятно, вы неверно сформулировали вопрос. ваша функция должна ограничивать ввод или выводить сообщение, что ввод ограничен? ибо ограничиваете кол-во символов вы через атрибут input, а не через js

Comment: элементов или именно цифр?

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/maxlength

функция вообще не нужна в этом случае, т.к. ввод символов можно ограничить аттрибутом `maxlength`, который есть у тега `input`. Например:

```
<input maxlength = "10"/>
```